# Wrap tag around certain words in string

Tags: c#, string

I have some text in a string. I want to find two specific words in the string, and wrap those words with a `<b>` tag.
I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bold.Split(' ').Count(); i++)
{
     if (myString.Split(' ')[i].Contains("MyWord"))
         myString.Split(' ')[i] = "<b" + myString.Split(' ')[i] + "</b";
}
```

And neither does this:

```
if (myString.Contains("MyWord"))
   myString = myString.Replace("MyWord", "< b >MyWord< /b >");
```

Comment: In the first case the assignment is done on a fresh new array obtained by split. you should save that in a initial variable and then do the assignment.

But it's a poor aproach tbh. 

The 2nd one is better and it should work. How did you test it ?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? The second example works, can you show us a concrete example of string you are searching for?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the second example. what is the result you are getting and what is the one you are expecting? By the way, you don't need the `if`, if you use `Replace` it will only replace if contains and duplicate the search.

Comment: You can use regex. See my answer

Comment: you can just use replace with given word as input with replacement , it should work without any loop or anything

Answer (score 2):

The second approach breaks when `MyWord` is part of a longer word - a [clbuttic problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). You can avoid it with regex:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\bMyWord\b", "<b>MyWord</b>");
```

`\b` markers ensure that `MyWord` must not be part of a longer word.

Comment: What about `MyWord.` a `dot` after the word if its the last word of the sentence

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex to replace all instances of a substring.

`Regex.Replace(myString, @"MyWord", "< b >MyWord< /b >");`